# Find lowest child of a tree

Tags: c#, tree, nodes, treenode

I have a function that add nodes :

```
public void AddNode(Guid ID, string name,  Guid parentNode)
{
  MyNode node = new MyNode ();
  node.ID = ID;
  node.Name = name;
  node.ParentNode = parentNode;

  AddNode(node);
}
```

How can I do a function that finds the lowest nodes?

Comment: Besides the mandatory "What have you tried?", your code show how to get the parent node but not how to get the child node.

Comment: too broad question. please specify what data structures you use.

Comment: lowest = leaf or root?

Comment: What do you define as "lowest"? Any node without children, or the ones with highest depth?

Comment: the lowest node, who does not have any child

Comment: @Lelezeus How should your code behave, if there is more than 1 "lowest node"?

Comment: if there is more then 1 lowest node the function should return all the nodes at lowest level . Each node has: ID[guid], name[string], Parent[guid]

Answer (score 1):

Without the code for the overloaded function AddNode(Node), we can only guess.

If you only store the link to the parent node, you can't go down in the tree because for that, you'd have to obtain the links to the children.
You could make your tree doubly-linked by also storing a link to the child node, or you could just store a link to the child node.
If you've done that, you can make a recursive breadth-first-search or a depth-first-search  beginning from the root to find your desired node.

Answer (score 0):

[how to find child nodes at root node [TreeView]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3767735/how-to-find-child-nodes-at-root-node-treeview)

Try this link for pointers and once you find a node with no children place it in a List/Dictionary/etc whatever you want to use.